# Placement of “Then” in a sentence as an adverb of sequence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverbs

> First, clean your room. Then, do your homework.
>
> First, clean your room. Do your homework then.

Is the second sentence grammatically correct? And is it used in daily speech?

Comment: Though *perhaps* grammatically correct, the second does  not sound natural to my ears. Instead, I'd say, "First, clean your room. Do your homework *afterwards*."

Comment: The second sentence places *then* in an unusual position, and so it is emphasized. I think it could be natural in that way.